# For Loop in Function not iterating over entire list/stopping iteration to quickly

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop

I have the following code:

```
oldlist = [42, 72, 32, 4, 94, 82, 67, 67, 89, 89, 89, 89, 5, 90, 5, 5]

def removeodds(thing):
    for i in reversed(thing):
        icount = thing.count(i)
        if icount % 2 > 0:
            while i in thing:
                thing.remove(i)
    return thing

newlist = removeodds(oldlist)
print(newlist)
```

This is the whole program.

The function is supposed to go over the list and look for any numbers that are repeated an odd number of times in the list. Then remove them in the while loop.

It does this by starting the for loop with i.

It then uses the count() function to see how many times the element i appears in the list (icount).
If icount, when divided by two, has a remainder, it would be an odd number. A while loop then goes over the list until i is removed.

I have the list being iterated over in reverse, because if it goes the other way, the elements shift in the list when they are being removed and the for loop ends up skipping indexes.

However, in the above program, when you run it, the for loop stops at 90 and then sends the list back, showing the following result:

```
[42, 72, 32, 4, 94, 82, 67, 67, 89, 89, 89, 89, 90]
```

I cannot figure out why it is doing this. It is supposed to show the following:

```
  [67, 67, 89, 89, 89, 89]
```

I tried adding numbers to the list and changing things around.
If you add another 5, in between 5 and 90, the program works.
However, the current list always stops the for loop at 90.
Once ran, the function is supposed to return a list that only includes numbers that appear in the list an even number of times.

Edit: I've read [the other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it-in-python) that was suggested as my question already being asked. But I should clarify that I cannot use list comprehension or other one-line comprehensions for this, and the function has to be an *in-place algorithm* (no new lists). Also, I want to reiterate that the program **works** when you add another 5, in between 5 and 90 in the list. However, when you run the function with the current above list, it doesn't work.

I was hoping someone would be able *to see **why** the function is acting like this and explain*, but I suppose what I can do is just mark all the elements that I want to get rid of and then remove them afterwards.

Edit 2: Just wanted to add that I found the solution:

```
oldlist = [42, 42, 72, 42, 72, 4, 94, 82, 67, 67, 89, 89, 89, 89, 5, 90, 5, 5]

def removeodds(thing):
    for i in thing[::-1]:
        icount = thing.count(i)
        if icount % 2 > 0:
            while i in thing:
                thing.remove(i)
    return thing

newlist = removeodds(oldlist) print(newlist)
```

Comment: Using `reversed()` is not enough to isolate the list (which you are modifying) from the elements. You can use: `for i in list(thing):`

Comment: @quamrana Hey! Your solution worked! But I still don't understand why.....

Comment: _I was hoping someone would be able to see why the function is acting like this and explain_ When you execute `for i in reversed(thing)`, it calls `reversed(thing)` **once** and then proceeds to iterate over those values.  Removing an item from the list does not re-evaluate the loop iterator; it is still iterating over the **original** values that were returned from `reversed(thing)`.  So the actual list contents are out of sync with the iterator.

Comment: @GetOverHere: In my suggestion: `list(thing)` this creates a brand new list with all the elements of `thing`. But, only the for loop has access to this list (and is thrown away soon after it is finished). This list is not subject to the mutations that occur in `thing.remove(i)`

Answer (score 1):

Don't modify lists whilst enumerating them.

You can achieve your objective more simply like this:

```
from collections import Counter

oldlist = [42, 72, 32, 4, 94, 82, 67, 67, 89, 89, 89, 89, 5, 90, 5, 5]

newlist = []

for n, v in Counter(oldlist).items():
    if v % 2 == 0:
        newlist.extend([n]*v)

print(newlist)
```

**Output:**

```
[67, 67, 89, 89, 89, 89]
```

Comment: The output has to also show the numbers of times each element appears in the list. So the output should be the following: [67, 67, 89, 89, 89, 89]

Comment: @GetOverHere Sorry, I missed the output requirement. Code edited

Answer (score 1):

The list is changing while you iterate - the `reversed` call just yields values from the list itself: it returns a specialized object that contains a reference to the initial list, and juggles the indices and `__iter__` so it can return what effectivelly works as a reversed list in O(1). Just iterate over a copy of it, for example, with
`for i in reversed(thing[:]):`

here, the slice index `[:]` means "create a new list with all the elements of this one  from the (first) to the (last)"

In order for not have, at any moment, a copy of the list (but keep in minds such copies are "shallow": all that is duplicated by `my_list[:]` are the references to the objects contained therein, not the objects themselves), you can make two passes: one selecting the indices to remove, and another to remove then:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
to_remove = [item for item in my_list if item % 2] # (or any other predicate than "item % 2"
for index in reversed(to_remove):
    del my_list[index]
```

This code will not create a copy of the list, but the removal can be expensive, as it depends on the list length for each item.

All in all, the "cheapest" way to remove items is to create a new list, copying all but the items you want removed. This is done in a single pass, with all elements being appended (so, O(1) in non-exceptional cases (when a list resize is triggered internally, for example))

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
my_list = [item for item in my_list if item % 2]
```

Comment: This is good, but I was trying to create an in-place algorithm without creating a new list.

Comment: a new list just copying over the interesting members would be the most efficient way, anyway - as removing items from a list is O(N) itself, removing M items is O(MxN). Copying allowed items will be O(N) + the complexity of the allowed item test.  But you can do to passes: a first `for` stores the indexes of the items to be removed in a `to_remove` list - then, loop over the reversed items in `to_remove`, instead of looping over `thing` and del each index from `thing`.